# Converting streamed buffers back into numbers?

Tags: node.js

I have an implementation of a Readable stream that generates 200 random numbers between 1-200:

```
/*
Readable that produces a list of 200 random numbers
*/
var stream = require('stream');

function Random(options) {
    // Inherits from stream.Readable
    stream.Readable.call(this, options);
    this._counter = 1;
};

Random.prototype = Object.create(stream.Readable.prototype);
Random.prototype.constructor = stream.Readable;

// Called whenever data is required from the stream
Random.prototype._read = function() {
    // Generate a random number between 1 and 200
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);
    var buf = new Buffer(randomNumber, 'utf8');

    this.push(buf);
    this._counter++;
    // Generate 200 random numbers, then stop by pushing null
    if (this._counter > 200) {
        this.push(null);
    }
};

module.exports = Random;
```

In my `main.js`, all I'm trying to do is instantiate the stream and decode each one of the chunks as they come in. However, I'm getting jibberish as my output -- what's the proper way to get it to print out all of my random numbers?

```
var Random = require('./random');

// Stream
var random = new Random();

random.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh -- got it. The Buffer constructor needs to take in a string, not an integer. Changing the `buf` instantiation line to:

```
var buf = new Buffer(randomNumber.toString());
```

did the trick.